# Npm not creating Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

When trying to install Grunt for the first time, and following many guides, I don't seem to be getting a Gruntfile.js in my project. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
macbookpro:Noemptytags $ sudo npm install grunt --save-dev
npm WARN package.json Noemptytags@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json Noemptytags@0.0.0 No README data
grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── which@1.0.5
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── exit@0.1.2
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)
├── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.15)
└── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.1)
```

It has created node_modules folder but no Gruntfile.js

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

the grunt module is just a runner plugin for your tasks. you need to create your gruntfile manually.

there is 1 option if you want it to be generated:

1. install [grunt-init](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-init) globally:

   `$ npm install grunt-init -g`
2. clone the [grunt-init-gruntfile-repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile)

   `$ git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile.git ~/.grunt-init/gruntfile`
3. run grunt init in your directory

   `$ grunt-init gruntfile`

voila

you could save yourself a lot of time, if you would use project-scaffolding-tools for your project. there are [grunt-init](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-init)-generators for jquery-plugins, gruntplugins. or even better, use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). that generates your project-structure plus a useful gruntfile!

Comment: I really hate using command line and now it seems I have to do it all the time. I don't know why 'getting started' installation assume that you know every step of the way. I would prefer a list of commands like
- npm install -g grunt-cli
- go to project
- npm init
- npm install
- npm install grunt --save-dev
- npm install grunt-init -g
- clone $ git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile.git ~/.grunt-init/gruntfile
- grunt-init gruntfile

Comment: if you hate to use the commandline, why did you choose grunt??? using grunt-init is just an option to make it easier for yourself. if you don't like it, go ahead and create the gruntfile by yourself in the editor of your choice! shouldn't be to difficult to create a new javascript file. you have to edit it anyway when it comes to configuring tasks, and you can decide which tasks excactly you want to use... edit: and the grunt-docs are really good on how to create a new gruntfile, configure tasks and so on!